# Rename the most recently used file

Tags: files

I have some files in /home/Desktop/Code directory. How can I change the file name which is last modified to a name "test.cpp" using terminal.

Comment: You can change file names using the `mv` command. Run `man mv` for more info about it.

Comment: Also with the `-t`option of `ls`command you can sort the files by modification date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `ls -t | head -n 1 | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' test.cpp`

Explanation:

`ls -t`  sort the files by last modification date

`head -n 1` selects the first name that previous command returned (last modified file)

`xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' test.cpp` this command execute the mv command replacing the '{}' with string received from standard input (in this case through the pipe) (The command would be `mv last_modified_file test.cpp`)

To avoid directories:

```
ls -t `find -maxdepth 1 -type f` | head -n 1 | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' test.cpp
```

`

Comment: Can you give a solutions which avoids last modified folders and only works for files. Your solution seems harmful.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: +1 since this is good in most cases, but mind also that it would break on filenames containing newlines

Comment: Yes, it's possible.